# A simple query in SQL

Tags: sql, count, group-by, having

I have 2 tables . each table has two columns.

```
DocumentNumber      price
```

I want to use a query to show same documentnumber and count of ducumentnumber in each table.
I used this code.

```
Select  Sheet.DocumentNumber , Sheet2.DocumentNumber ,Count(sheet.documentnumber) , Count(sheet2.documentnumber) 

        From Sheet,Sheet2
        where sheet.DocumentNumber=sheet2.DocumentNumber

        group by sheet.DocumentNumber , Sheet2.DocumentNumber
```

but instead of counting document numbers it shows me the Cartesian of two column.

And I want to show price of each table and (sheet.price) minus (sheet2.price)

please complete my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proper join syntax.  In particular, for this, you should use `full outer join` because it is possible that a document has no records in one or the other table.

Second, because you don't want to count duplicates, you need to count something.  The following assumes that there is an `id` column (of some sort) in each table:

```
Select  coalesce(s.DocumentNumber, s2.DocumentNumber) as DocumentNumber,
        Count(distinct s.id), Count(distinct s2.id)
From Sheet s full outer join
     Sheet2 s2
     on s.DocumentNumber = s2.DocumentNumber
 group by  coalesce(s.DocumentNumber, s2.DocumentNumber);
```

If you don't have an `id` column, or if your database does not support `full outer join`, the following will also work:

```
select DocumentNumber, max(cnt_s) as cnt_s, max(cnt_s2) as cnt_s2
from ((select DocumentNumber, count(*) as cnt_s, 0 as cnt_s2
       from Sheet s
       group by DocumentNumber
      ) union all
      (select DocumentNumber, 0, count(*) as cnt_s2
       from Sheet2 s2
       group by DocumentNumber
      )
     ) t
group by DocumentNumber;
```

EDIT:

The `union all` approach is actually better for the price:

```
select DocumentNumber, max(cnt_s) as cnt_s, max(cnt_s2) as cnt_s2,
       max(price_s) - max(price_s2)
from ((select DocumentNumber, count(*) as cnt_s, 0 as cnt_s2,
              sum(price) as price_s, 0 as price_s2
       from Sheet s
       group by DocumentNumber
      ) union all
      (select DocumentNumber, 0, count(*) as cnt_s2,
              0, sum(price) as price_s2
       from Sheet2 s2
       group by DocumentNumber
      )
     ) t
group by DocumentNumber;
```

Note:  This version treats a missing price as 0.  You might want to replace the `0` with `NULL` for that situation.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. All queries you showed ,e are working. I used the 3rd one. it's awesome. but in 3rd one I want to show the price of first sheet and price of second sheet. and then the minus between price1 and price2